# Understanding of Gauss law using vector fields

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, gauss-law, vector-fields

I was going through the conventions and terminologies followed to describe the magnetic interactions. I understood that the field lines are just a simpler representation of the magnetic interaction described in terms of a vector field.

So those field lines basically relates to the line of force due to magnetic interactions. I hope this understanding is right.

And the magnetic flux is defined as net magnetic field lines crossing the area. And so flux indirectly relates to the magnetic forces.

After all these understandings I considered Gauss law of magnetism which states that the total magnetic flux through a closed surface is equal to zero. The observation that magnetic monopoles do not exist supports this law.

Without involving surface integrals concept (Area vector)  why can't I say If the flux is zero, Field lines are zero? And if yes Can I say that the magnetic force inside a closed surface is zero?

But this conflicts with my general understanding of the field line. Why should a close surface affect the force due to magnetic interaction?

If the surfacae integral is necessary to answer to this Question why the surface area vector is related to force vector in Gauss Law?

Comment: Magnetic force is *not* along the magnetic field lines. $\mathbf F=q\mathbf v\times\mathbf B$. The force is actually perpendicular to the field lines.

Comment: The term "line of force" probably shouldn't be used to describe magnetic field lines. For a magnetic field acting on charged particles, the magnetic force acts perpendicular to the magnetic field lines, not along them.

Comment: @probably_someone comment battle

Comment: Also, Gauss's Law of Magnetism is a _consequence_ of the fact that we have never observed magnetic monopoles to exist. It doesn't support that fact; support for that fact comes from observations.

Comment: Ok I have edited a few lines.

Comment: If magnetic force is perpendicular to field lines then the vector field equivalent will also be perpendicular at every point in space where magnetic interaction is feasible?

Comment: Still incorrect. Gauss's Law of Magnetism doesn't support the observations; rather, it's a consequence of the observations (and therefore _is supported by_ those observations). We make and test physical laws by making observations, not the other way around.

Comment: Magnetic force doesn't have a vector field equivalent, at least not in $\mathbb{R}^3$, because magnetic force on a charged particle is _also_ perpendicular to that particle's velocity (and, in fact, a stationary charged particle will experience no magnetic force regardless of the magnetic field at its location). In $\mathbb{R}^6$ you might be able to construct such a vector field (three dimensions for position, three dimensions for velocity), but that may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: I am not understanding why magnetic interaction are modelled using lines called  field lines.

Comment: Because the field lines show you what the magnetic field looks like. The point we're trying to get across is that the relationship between magnetic field and magnetic force is more complicated than you assume.

Comment: @VKJ It is correct when talking about electric fields that the field lines are parallel to the force the field gives to a charged particle. However, this is not true for magnetism. Maybe this is where you are getting hung up.

Comment: Also note that you can have magnetic fields without even thinking about particles interacting with those fields. So trying to throw forces into this just makes things more complicated.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that information. Now If we say flux is higher implies field lines are higher in that unit area. Then force related to those field lines are higher. But as per gauss law, saying flux inside a closed surface is zero brings out any change in the magnetic force?

Comment: Flux goes _through_ surfaces. Referring to "the flux inside a closed surface" suggests that flux is a thing that inhabits the volume contained by the surface, which is incorrect. Saying that the net flux (field lines pointing out minus field lines pointing in) through a surface is zero will tell you absolutely nothing about the actual magnetic field strength without some extra assumptions about symmetry, just like $x-y=0$ tells you nothing about the actual value of $x$ unless you also know something about $y$.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your main questions:

> why can't I say If the flux is zero, Field lines are zero?

The flux through a particular area is the *difference* of the number of magnetic field lines pointing one way through an area and the number of magnetic fields pointing the other way. If you have the same number of field lines pointing into and out of a particular surface, then the flux will be zero even if the field is nonzero. For an analogy, it isn't correct to say: if $x-y=0$, then $x$ and $y$ must both be $0$. There are many combinations of $x$ and $y$ that will satisfy that equation, just like there are many nonzero field configurations that will give you zero flux through a particular surface.

> Why should a close surface affect the force due to magnetic interaction?

Applying Gauss's Law for Magnetism closed surface is a mathematical tool that we use to *describe* how a magnetic field looks. It often simplifies what would otherwise be a difficult calculation; however, it is by no means the only way that we have to calculate the magnetic field (for example, the Biot-Savart Law is another useful tool). It doesn't *affect* anything about the field (and certainly doesn't affect the force, since the relationship between magnetic field and magnetic force is complicated).

Comment: This clear some of doubts. But in first place why should we describe how a field is going to look if it's relation to magnetic force is complicated?

Comment: @VKJ Because the magnetic field is _necessary_ to describe the magnetic force. It just isn't a _complete_ description of magnetic force - for example, for the force on a charged particle, we also need its velocity.

Comment: So can I say that for a given velocity the points in area where flux is more will experience more force?

Comment: @VKJ It isn't really correct to talk about the flux at a particular point. Flux is defined as being _through an area_ of a particular size. If you want to talk about the magnetic field at a particular point, then you should look at the _flux density_ at that point (in other words, how much the flux through a tiny area about that point changes if that area is increased by a tiny amount). In fact, magnetic field is sometimes referred to in older books as "magnetic flux density" for that reason.

Comment: And I am still not understanding the importance of taking surface Integral of a visualisation tool - the field lines. And how the direction of field lines are know?

Comment: @VKJ Even then, it's not guaranteed that the magnetic force will be greater, for a given velocity, at a point with higher magnetic field strength (i.e. magnetic flux density). This is because the magnitude of the magnetic force also depends on the _angle_ between the magnetic field at that point and the velocity of the charged particle. If the particle is travelling along the magnetic field line, it will experience no magnetic force at that point. This is why we use equations like $\mathbf{F}=q\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B}$; they contain all of the information I've been telling you.

Comment: @VKJ You're not taking a surface integral of a visualization tool. You're taking the surface integral of what that visualization tool _represents_. The magnetic field is a vector field that has a value at every single point in space. Magnetic field _lines_, on the other hand, are merely samplings of values of the magnetic field at particular points. We use magnetic field lines to describe magnetic flux qualitatively because it's easy to visualize, but in any actual quantitative calculation, you integrate over the actual, continuous magnetic field.

Comment: @VKJ Without any additional assumptions, the direction of the field lines cannot be obtained purely from Gauss's Law for Magnetism. You need more information about a problem to determine the magnetic field. For example, if I told you that a particular field configuration looks the same from every direction, then, on any spherical surface, it must be uniform in strength and must be either pointing radially outward, pointing inward, or zero. Gauss's Law for Magnetism tells us that the flux through any sphere is zero, so the first two situations are impossible and the field is zero everywhere.

Comment: @ probably_someone I show my gratitude for given intuition and your patience. But I getting stuck with different parameter like magnetic field , magnetic flux , magnetic flux intensity and magnetic flux density used to model magnetic interaction.I can't wrap my mind around this interactions using these parameter.

Comment: And in general flux is related to flow through an area.What is flowing here?Is it magnetic field flowing?

Comment: And why does only  the flux parameter is playing important role in performamce of electro mechanical devices like DC machine.

Comment: And why does iron particle arrange themselves along field lines under proper condition?

Comment: Comments are not the appropriate place to ask new questions that are only distantly related to the original question.